# Are the poles of the resolvent of a Hermitian operator real?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

The resolvent of a matrix $M$ is defined as $$R_M(z)=(z-M)^{-1}.$$ The spectrum of $M$ can then be defined as the set of points $\lambda$ for which $R_M(\lambda)$ is singular. Since all the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real, and all elements of the spectrum of a matrix are eigenvalues of that matrix, it follows that all elements of the spectrum of a Hermitian matrix are real.

This is great, but I'm interested in the generalization to the operator case. Consider a Hermitian operator $H$ whose resolvent is $$R_H(z)=(z-H)^{-1}$$ and which has a spectrum defined by the singularities of $R_H(z)$. All the eigenvalues of $H$ must be real due to the hermiticity of $H$. However, my understanding is that there can be elements of the spectrum of an operator which are not eigenvalues of that operator. Can a Hermitian operator have elements of its spectrum which are outside of the set of eigenvalues, and can these eigenvalues be complex?

Answer (score 0):

If a Hermitian operator has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then it must be real because of the standard argument involving $Hx=\lambda x$ for some $x\ne 0$:
$$
    \lambda\|x\|^2=\langle \lambda x,x\rangle=\langle Hx,x\rangle = \langle x,Hx\rangle=\langle x,\lambda x\rangle=\overline{\lambda}\|x\|^2.
$$
Any $\lambda$ in the spectrum of $H$ must be real; if such $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue, then it is an *approximate eigenvalue*, meaning that there is a sequence of unit vectors $\{ x_n \}$ such that $\|(H-\lambda I)x_n\|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I'm not asking about the eigenvalues of H though, I'm asking about the eigenvalues of the resolvent of H. I believe these can be complex.

Comment: @Ian : If $(z-A)^{-1}x=\lambda x$ and $\lambda\ne 0$, then $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ and $x=\lambda(z-A)x$ or $(\lambda z-1)x=Ax$, which makes $x$ an eigenvector of $A$.